# How to add an additional column to the shipping methods list in the WooCommerce dashboard?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Such a story!

There is this code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_init', 'woocommerce_shipping_instances_form_fields_filters');
function woocommerce_shipping_instances_form_fields_filters(){
    foreach( WC()->shipping->get_shipping_methods() as $shipping_method ) {
        add_filter('woocommerce_shipping_instance_form_fields_' . $shipping_method->id, 'shipping_methods_additional_custom_field');
    }
}

function shipping_methods_additional_custom_field( $settings ) {
    $settings['shipping_comment'] = array(
        'title'         => __('Shipping Comment', 'woocommerce'),
        'type'          => 'textarea', 
        'placeholder'   => __( 'Enter any additional comments for this shipping method.', 'woocommerce' ),
    );
    return $settings;
}
```

which adds an additional comment field when editing the shipping method in the Woocommerce settings

[image]

How can I add an additional column in the list of shipping methods in the Woocommerce settings and have these comments displayed in it?

Here

[image]